# Unable to connect to oracle database from rhel5

Tags: oracle, odbc, rhel5, obiee

I have an instance of OBIEE 11g installed on a RHEL5 machine. When I try to run an Analysis. I receive the following error

> Error Codes: OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P
>   State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 43119] Query Failed: [nQSError: 16001] ODBC error state: IM002 code: 0 message: [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Data source name not found and no default driver specified. (HY000)

But I have already updated `/u01/oracle/obiee_home/instances/instance1/bifoundation/OracleBIApplication/coreapplication/setup/odbc.ini` to include this ODBC connection.

Any ideas on what can be going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps ODBC is looking somewhere else for odbc.ini.

Comment: did you edit ORACLE_INSTANCE/bifoundation/OracleBIApplication/coreapplication/setup/user.sh as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10540/deploy_rpd.htm#CHDFEEHC